# Android apply animation to button background

Tags: android, animation, button, drawable

I have a button which currently has an animation assigned to it on click:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.startAnimation(animRotate);
}
});
```

Here is an example of the button in XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="@string/btnText"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btnIcon"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

The animation works spot on, however on the button itself there is a text value and a drawable value, and I would like to be able to target the drawable and animate that only. I have searched all over the net and everything appears to be targeting objects by their id without any background/drawable selection.

Any feedback is welcome, even if its just to inform me that it can't be done.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a `FrameLayout` with the `TextView` and the `Button` and animate only the `Button`.